# Python: get the variable out of loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following piece of code:

```
for response_i in response['response']:

  var_1=None
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_data':
      var_1=response_i['objcontent'][0]['title']
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_data' and response_i['objcontent'][0]['title'] == var_1:
    print(var_1)

  dim_1=None
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues':
      dim_1=response_i['objcontent'][0]['title']
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues' and response_i['objcontent'][0]['title'] == dim_1:
      print(dim_1)

  ab=[var_1, dim_1]
  print(ab)
```

I updated the question.
following is the output:

```
['tos', None]
[None, None]
[None, 'lat']
[None, None]
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
['tos', 'lat']
```

I appreciate any suggestion to solve this issue

Comment: What does `response['response']` contain?

Comment: Use copy and paste for entering code to make sure that the indentation is as you wrote it. Your original [works as desired](http://ideone.com/TeL9eM).

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: Remove `var_1=None` and `dim_1=None`, then move `print(ab)` out of the loop

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I moved  ab=[var_1, dim_1], print(ab) out of the loop

Answer (score 2):

Use the generator to produce the result that you want, then print it.

```
def PrintGen():
    for response_i in response['response']:
        if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_data' or response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues':
            yield response_i['objcontent'][0]['title']
ab =PrintGen()
listab =list(ab)
print(listab)
```

Generators are used to yield objects which meet the demand, they are proper for you.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, should convert the data into a pandas dataframe and drop the None values

```
import pandas as pd


data = []

data.append([var_1, dim_1])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['var_1', 'dim_1'])
df = df.dropna(how = 'all')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append values to `ab`, when the values are not `None`.Then you will need to instantiate and print `ab` outside of the loop.

```
ab = []
for response_i in response['response']:
  var_1=None
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_data':
      var_1=response_i['objcontent'][0]['title']
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_data' and response_i['objcontent'][0]['title'] == var_1:
    print(var_1)
    ab.append(var1)

  dim_1=None
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues':
      dim_1=response_i['objcontent'][0]['title']
  if response_i['objkey'] == 'explorecube_dimvalues' and response_i['objcontent'][0]['title'] == dim_1:
      print(dim_1)
      ab.append(dim1)

print(ab)
```